# Styling the second sidebar

Tags: php, css, sidebar

Ok so i added a second sidebar to my site, only problem is styling the widgets.

here is the code i am using in my functions.php file

```
// Widgets plugin: intializes the plugin after the widgets above have passed snuff
function wpbx_widgets_init() {
if ( !function_exists('register_sidebars') ) {
    return;
}
// Formats the theme widgets, adding readability-improving whitespace
$p = array(
    'before_widget'  =>   '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'   =>   "</li>\n",
    'before_title'   =>   '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'    =>   "</h3>\n"
);

register_sidebars( 2, $p );
}
```

I just don't know how to style the second sidebar widget, how do i do this?

I want to use the same code but different class titles

Comment: you can give ids to your sidebars and style sidebars based on ids.Is their any problem with ids based styling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`register_sidebars()` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars), the CSS ID of the sidebars gets incremented by default.  In other words, if you're not explicitly setting the `id` array value -- and in your code sample above, you aren't -- you would end up with sidebars with CSS IDs of `sidebar` and `sidebar-2`.  You can then style them differently in your CSS file (be it `style.css` or a custom one that you've added):

```
#sidebar {
    /* Styles */
}

#sidebar-2 {
    /* Styles for the 2nd sidebar */
}
```